# Mocking files and unit tests with temporaryFolder

Tags: java, testing, mocking, temporary-files

I have a method which is searching and adding all java files in directory to List:

```
public List<File> findJavaFiles(File root, String path) {
    String suffix = ".java";
    List<File> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (root.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = root.listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                list.addAll(findJavaFiles(file, suffix));
            }
        }
    } else if (root.getName().endsWith(suffix)) {
        list.add(root);
    }
    return list;
}
```

It works, but the problem is that I want to create unit test (I'm starting "fun" with mocks tests). I know I should use temporaryFolder and mock java files, so I have something like this:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temporaryFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {
file1 = mock(File.class);
    when(file1.getName()).thenReturn("file1.java");
    when(file1.length()).thenReturn(1L);
    file2 = mock(File.class);
    when(file2.getName()).thenReturn("file2.java");
    when(file2.length()).thenReturn(5L);
    file3 = mock(File.class);
    when(file3.getName()).thenReturn("file3.java");
    when(file3.length()).thenReturn(3L);
    file4 = mock(File.class);
    when(file4.getName()).thenReturn("file4.jpg");
    when(file4.length()).thenReturn(10L);
    temporaryFolder.newFile(file1.getName());
    temporaryFolder.newFile(file2.getName());
    temporaryFolder.newFile(file3.getName());
    temporaryFolder.newFile(file4.getName());
```

And unit test:

```
@Test
public void findJavaFilesIsCorrect() {
    //given
    List<File> expectedResult = List.of(file1, file2, file3);
    //when
    when(fileService.findJavaFiles(ArgumentMatchers.anyString())).thenCallRealMethod();
    List<File> result = fileService.findJavaFiles(System.getProperty(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
    //then
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
}
```

And test failed... Result List is empty... But I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the java.io.tmpdir value.

Comment: Hmmm... no, where should i do it?

Comment: How are you running the program. And can you print/check the value?

Comment: i'm using that method in other method

Comment: public Map<String, Long> countCreatedFilesByWeekday(String path) {
        List<File> javaFiles = findJavaFiles(path);
        return javaFiles.stream()
                .map(this::getFileCreationDate)
                .map(Date::new)
                .map(this::getDayFromDate)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @ouflak What makes this not an answer?  It's an attempt to solve the question, albeit a poor one...

Comment: @Anonymous, It looks like they have edited to be an answer, which is good. At the time I reviewed, it was merely commentary on the original post.

Comment: @ouflak Actually, now that I look, someone else edited it to be an answer.  Sometimes the meta-effect can be beneficial...